# Textbook C Code produces incorrrect output

Tags: c

I am learning C from a text. An example code provided by the author is:

```
#include <math.h>

main()

{ int i;

  printf("\t Number \t\t Square Root of Number\n\n");

  for (i=0; i<=360; ++i)
           printf("\t %d \t\t\t %d \n",i, sqrt((double) i));

}
```

which on my computer produces an incorrect output I don't understand:

```
 Number          Square Root of Number 

 0           259 
 1           515 
 2           771 
 3           1027 
 4           1283 
 5           1539 
 6           1795 
 7           2051 
 8           2307 
 9           2563 
 10              2819 
 11              3075 
 12              3331 
 13              3587 
 14              3843 
 15              4099 
 16              4355 
 17              4611 
 18              4867 
 19              5123 
 20              5379 
 21              5635 
 22              5891 
 23              6147 
 24              6403 
 25              6659 
 26              6915 
 27              7171 
 28              7427 
 29              7683 
 30              7939 
 31              8195 
 32              8451 
 33              8707 
 34              8963 
 35              9219 
 36              9475 
 37              9731 
 38              9987 
 39              10243 
 40              10499 
 41              10755 
 42              11011 
 43              11267 
 44              11523 
 45              11779 
 46              12035 
 47              12291 
 48              12547 
 49              12803 
 50              13059 
 51              13315 
 52              13571 
 53              13827 
 54              14083 
 55              14339 
 56              14595 
 57              14851 
 58              15107 
 59              15363 
 60              15619 
 61              15875 
 62              16131 
 63              16387 
 64              16643 
 65              16899 
 66              17155 
 67              17411 
 68              17667 
 69              17923 
 70              18179 
 71              18435 
 72              18691 
 73              18947 
 74              19203 
 75              19459 
 76              19715 
 77              19971 
 78              20227 
 79              20483 
 80              20739 
 81              20995 
 82              21251 
 83              21507 
 84              21763 
 85              22019 
 86              22275 
 87              22531 
 88              22787 
 89              23043 
 90              23299 
 91              23555 
 92              23811 
 93              24067 
 94              24323 
 95              24579 
 96              24835 
 97              25091 
 98              25347 
 99              25603 
 100             25859 
 101             26115 
 102             26371 
 103             26627 
 104             26883 
 105             27139 
 106             27395 
 107             27651 
 108             27907 
 109             28163 
 110             28419 
 111             28675 
 112             28931 
 113             29187 
 114             29443 
 115             29699 
 116             29955 
 117             30211 
 118             30467 
 119             30723 
 120             30979 
 121             31235 
 122             31491 
 123             31747 
 124             32003 
 125             32259 
 126             32515 
 127             32771 
 128             33027 
 129             33283 
 130             33539 
 131             33795 
 132             34051 
 133             34307 
 134             34563 
 135             34819 
 136             35075 
 137             35331 
 138             35587 
 139             35843 
 140             36099 
 141             36355 
 142             36611 
 143             36867 
 144             37123 
 145             37379 
 146             37635 
 147             37891 
 148             38147 
 149             38403 
 150             38659 
 151             38915 
 152             39171 
 153             39427 
 154             39683 
 155             39939 
 156             40195 
 157             40451 
 158             40707 
 159             40963 
 160             41219 
 161             41475 
 162             41731 
 163             41987 
 164             42243 
 165             42499 
 166             42755 
 167             43011 
 168             43267 
 169             43523 
 170             43779 
 171             44035 
 172             44291 
 173             44547 
 174             44803 
 175             45059 
 176             45315 
 177             45571 
 178             45827 
 179             46083 
 180             46339 
 181             46595 
 182             46851 
 183             47107 
 184             47363 
 185             47619 
 186             47875 
 187             48131 
 188             48387 
 189             48643 
 190             48899 
 191             49155 
 192             49411 
 193             49667 
 194             49923 
 195             50179 
 196             50435 
 197             50691 
 198             50947 
 199             51203 
 200             51459 
 201             51715 
 202             51971 
 203             52227 
 204             52483 
 205             52739 
 206             52995 
 207             53251 
 208             53507 
 209             53763 
 210             54019 
 211             54275 
 212             54531 
 213             54787 
 214             55043 
 215             55299 
 216             55555 
 217             55811 
 218             56067 
 219             56323 
 220             56579 
 221             56835 
 222             57091 
 223             57347 
 224             57603 
 225             57859 
 226             58115 
 227             58371 
 228             58627 
 229             58883 
 230             59139 
 231             59395 
 232             59651 
 233             59907 
 234             60163 
 235             60419 
 236             60675 
 237             60931 
 238             61187 
 239             61443 
 240             61699 
 241             61955 
 242             62211 
 243             62467 
 244             62723 
 245             62979 
 246             63235 
 247             63491 
 248             63747 
 249             64003 
 250             64259 
 251             64515 
 252             64771 
 253             65027 
 254             65283 
 255             65539 
 256             65795 
 257             66051 
 258             66307 
 259             66563 
 260             66819 
 261             67075 
 262             67331 
 263             67587 
 264             67843 
 265             68099 
 266             68355 
 267             68611 
 268             68867 
 269             69123 
 270             69379 
 271             69635 
 272             69891 
 273             70147 
 274             70403 
 275             70659 
 276             70915 
 277             71171 
 278             71427 
 279             71683 
 280             71939 
 281             72195 
 282             72451 
 283             72707 
 284             72963 
 285             73219 
 286             73475 
 287             73731 
 288             73987 
 289             74243 
 290             74499 
 291             74755 
 292             75011 
 293             75267 
 294             75523 
 295             75779 
 296             76035 
 297             76291 
 298             76547 
 299             76803 
 300             77059 
 301             77315 
 302             77571 
 303             77827 
 304             78083 
 305             78339 
 306             78595 
 307             78851 
 308             79107 
 309             79363 
 310             79619 
 311             79875 
 312             80131 
 313             80387 
 314             80643 
 315             80899 
 316             81155 
 317             81411 
 318             81667 
 319             81923 
 320             82179 
 321             82435 
 322             82691 
 323             82947 
 324             83203 
 325             83459 
 326             83715 
 327             83971 
 328             84227 
 329             84483 
 330             84739 
 331             84995 
 332             85251 
 333             85507 
 334             85763 
 335             86019 
 336             86275 
 337             86531 
 338             86787 
 339             87043 
 340             87299 
 341             87555 
 342             87811 
 343             88067 
 344             88323 
 345             88579 
 346             88835 
 347             89091 
 348             89347 
 349             89603 
 350             89859 
 351             90115 
 352             90371 
 353             90627 
 354             90883 
 355             91139 
 356             91395 
 357             91651 
 358             91907 
 359             92163 
 360             92419
```

Any idea or clue as to why? If its obvious maybe point to a reference that will point out some stupid mistake I have made?

Comment: Do you know the type of the return value of sqrt()?

Comment: `%d` is for integers. Look at the man page for `printf` to find out how to print a double.

Comment: If you compile using gcc and use the `-Wall` option to turn on all warnings, you would see something like this: ` warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("\t %d \t\t\t %d \n",i, sqrt((double) i));`

Comment: Is this really from the textbook?

Comment: Two errors in this program: `main()` is no longer standard and a format specifier error as addressed in answers below. My hint: throw away your C text book and get a decent one.

Comment: Which textbook is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read up on this: [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

And use `%f` for `double` not `%d` which is for `int`

Comment: Okay. I am unclear why such a "simple"mistake could be printed in a textbook though. Why does the %d produce such an output? I would think it would just not compile or something, but it produces numbers.

Comment: @FritzMcNasty C does not hold your hand.  It trusts you know what you are doing.

Comment: Yep, that's a bad mistake to have in a textbook for beginners. Very unfair. You have definitely copied it exactly? ... it wasn't this was it: `(int)sqrt(i)`?
Because that would then cast the sqrt return to an integer (and round it down), which would make the %d correct.

Comment: @FritzMcNasty I will say that if you do want the compiler to catch some things that you probably shouldn't be doing, you should compile with all warnings and set warnings to errors. `-Wall -Wpedantic -Werror` will catch a lot.  It would, in fact, have prevented you from compiling that code.

Comment: @noelicus I was curious and found this code here: https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node3.html

Comment: That is a university exercise by the look of it - the error might be deliberate for you to find! If it was printed in a book I'd be more concerned!!

Comment: @noelicus looks like the exercise is mean to teach the use of libraries, not debug.  I'd just chalk it up to a careless mistake in modifying the previous exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong [format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) here:

```
printf("\t %d \t\t\t %d \n",i, sqrt((double) i));
```

Make sure to use `%f` for variables of type `double` (what a function like `sqrt()` returns):

```
printf("\t %d \t\t\t %f \n",i, sqrt((double) i));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used a wrong format specifier. 
Try,

```
printf("\t %d \t\t\t %f \n" ,i , sqrt((double) i));
```

`%f` for `double`. Good luck.